# Duplicate modules error with exrm release

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using elixir `1.1.0`, exrm version `0.19.9`, httpoison is `0.8` 
`HTTPoison` is used by my app, and other hex package called `gcm` which has `HTTPoison` in its applications, when I remove the `gcm` hex package from `mix` file, it works fine. 
Is there a clean way to resolve these dependencies?

```
===> Provider (release) failed with: {error,
                                             {rlx_prv_assembler,
                                              {release_script_generation_error,
                                               systools_make,
                                               {duplicate_modules,
                                                [{{'Elixir.HTTPoison.Response',
                                                   httpoison,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/httpoison-0.8.0/ebin"},
                                                  {'Elixir.HTTPoison.Response',
                                                   cabs,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/cabs-0.0.1/ebin"}},
                                                 {{'Elixir.HTTPoison.Error',
                                                   httpoison,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/httpoison-0.8.0/ebin"},
                                                  {'Elixir.HTTPoison.Error',
                                                   cabs,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/cabs-0.0.1/ebin"}},
                                                 {{'Elixir.HTTPoison.Base',
                                                   httpoison,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/httpoison-0.8.0/ebin"},
                                                  {'Elixir.HTTPoison.Base',
                                                   cabs,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/cabs-0.0.1/ebin"}},
                                                 {{'Elixir.HTTPoison.AsyncStatus',
                                                   httpoison,
                                                   "/home/vysakh/propro/phoenix/cabs/rel/cabs/lib/httpoison-0.8.0/ebin"},
                                                  {'Elixir.HTTPoison.AsyncStatus',
                                                   cabs,
```

My `mix.exs` file

```
 defmodule Cabs.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

 def project do
    [app: :cabs,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 1.0",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      compilers: [:phoenix] ++ Mix.compilers,
      build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      deps: deps]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information
  def application do
    [mod: {Cabs, []},
      applications: [
        :phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger,
        :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :inflex,
      :httpoison, :gcm

      ]
    ]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.0.3"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 1.1"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.1"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
      {:mailgun, "~> 0.1.2"},
      {:httpoison, "~> 0.8"},
      {:gcm, "~> 1.0.0"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
  end
end
```

Weird as it sounds, it worked after I removed `httpoison` from one of the library that is using in `applications`, had to include the github url of the fork (https://github.com/vysakh0/gcm)

Comment: I'd post your mix.exs as well if you can.  I think that will be helpful to figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Sorry :( Now, I've updated with `mix.exs`., I tried to emulate the same with another `elixir` app involving two or more packages with same dependencies, it worked. The closest issue I can find is https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/701

Comment: Found the solution, it was because I had another mix project inside my `lib`,  which had `deps` inside it, hence there were duplication of modules.